# Laravel class 'navigation' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to build the navigation tree from the database but I keep getting class not found error. The database table is created as well

```
class Navigation extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'navigation';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('navigation', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('navigation', 'parent_id', 'id');

    }

    public static function tree()
    {
        return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 4, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your folders is this file located. Did you create this file with `artisan make:model` and/or have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: `return $this->hasOne('navigation', 'id', 'parent_id');` -- it should not be just `'navigation'` -- it should be that model's **class name** instead ... e.g.  `Navigation::class`. **P.S.** So far it has nothing to do with PhpStorm.

Comment: i made it with artisan make:model Notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the default Laravel structure change `'navigation'` to `'App/Navigation'`

```
class Navigation extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'navigation';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App/Navigation', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App/Navigation', 'parent_id', 'id');

    }
```